# Creating new task through WebHook with Asana API

Tags: webhooks, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I am working with a form system very similar to WUFOO that allows me to send data to an external website using WebHooks.

I have been able to connect my form to my ASANA system through Zapier but I cannot seem to get the API system to operate correctly. Can someone please advise or assist me on what I am doing incorrectly here?

In the screenshot note the following:
- Web URL functions for any web URL (https or http)
- HTTP method has POST, PUT, or GET options
- Data format allows me to input virtually anything so I can match up form fields with any necessary names for ASANA.

I simply cannot get the system to connect to ASANA. Please help me.

[Screen shot of WebHook Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAGGq.png)

Comment: You will have to provide more specific information about what 3rd party you are using and what pieces of the workflow you have set up and which you are having trouble with.

Comment: I am using a form system called Machform. I can get the form to submit but it seems as though ASANA is not receiving the WebHook to grab the data from the form fields.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to your exact form builder but assuming it does what it says it is doing you can try the following. I'll use creating a task as an example.

1. Create a personal access token in Asana. To do this log in to Asana, click the icon in the top right corner and open "My profile settings". Go to the apps tab and create a personal access token. You will only ever see this token once so create a new one if you lose it. Also retrieve your workspace id, you can get it by opening app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces while logged in.
2. Now back to your form. For the website url place the specific endpoint you want to hit at Asana. For example, lets create a new task:
   https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks
3. Under the HTTP Method you want to select POST
4. Under the HTTP Headers you want to specify something like (replace 0/1234abcd with your access token):

   ```
   {
     "Authorization": "Bearer 0/1234abcd",
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
   ```
5. You can use Send Raw Data and specify something like the following in the raw data section (replace 1234 with your workspace id):

   ```
   {
     "data": {
       "workspace": 1234,
       "name": "The name of the task"
     }
   }
   ```

You can of course add other fields- please see the API reference for more information:
https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks

Let me know if that works for you.